# Stack level too deep when using `method_missing`

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I have a dummy object that always yield itself:

```rb
x = Object.new; x.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) { |*| x }

x.foo.bar.baz == x # => true
```

I wanted to simplify it, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore:

```rb
x = Object.new; def x.method_missing(*) x end

x.foo # raises SystemStackError, stack level too deep
```

Why is a `SystemStackError` raised in that last example?

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

The `def` creates a new scope for local variables, whereas the closure keeps local variables.

```rb
x = Object.new # declares a local variable `x`
def x.method_missing(*)
  x # actually tries to call the method `x`, which is itself missing.
end
```

```rb
x = 42
p local_variables # => [:x, :b]
def a; local_variables; end
b = -> { local_variables }
p a # => []
p b.call # => [:x, :b]
```

Per comment, to fix it you could use `self`, or for a shorter declaration:

```rb
X=Object.new;def X.method_missing(*) X end # Global variables are in the global scope
```

Comment: To fix your code, return `self` instead of `x`